# How do I create a diff file with visual source safe?

Tags: version-control, diff, visual-sourcesafe

If I want to create a patch file of a directory with svn, all I need to do is right click on the directory, click tortoiseSVN, then click create patch, and I have a nice patch file of the differences between the latest version of the code on svn and the code on my machine.

Is there a way to build a diff file buried within VSS or is it just another part of VSS that does not work?

Comment: You can make source control use another diff tool, https://krishnakumartm.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/using-winmerge-as-a-visual-source-safe-5-0-diff-tool/

Answer (score 0):

With VSS, you can right-click on a project, click Show Difference. In the Project Difference dialog box, you can click Report icon to get a text file with the diff result. Not sure if that is what you need.

Comment: That's more than I thought it could do, but most source control can list the changes in the files, so that you can apply a patch file. Creating a real patch file was what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't think VSS can create a real patch file. If you find a way to do that, I'd love to know.