# How to create a patch compatible to GIT in VSS(Visual Source safe)

Tags: git, visual-sourcesafe

We are migrating from VSS and SVN to git.
We use command like below to generate the patch in SVN

```
SVN diff --git  -r  20566:21030 >> patchFile.patch
```

Similarly, I want to create a patch in VSS. Any body have idea on this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19694331/520162. There, they say that it's not possible to create a patch file from VSS at all. Apart of this, you just need to create a **unified** diff in order to apply it using `git apply`, so there's no special git patch needed...

Answer (score 0):

As example you can try https://github.com/azarkevich/VssPowerTools it has ability to create patch via UI.

But seems better will be migrate VSS repo to SVN or GIT directly and then generate patches